# Angular ERROR ReferenceError: toastr is not defined

Tags: angular-services

I have correctly imported the toastr styles and script into the angular.json file yet getting reference error.

```
declare let toastr;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-events-list',
  template: `
  <div>
    <h1>Upcoming Angular Events</h1>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
      <div *ngFor="let event of events" class="col-md-5">
        <app-event-thumbnail (click)="handleThumbnailClick(event.name)" [event]="event"></app-event-thumbnail>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./events-list.component.css']
})
  handleThumbnailClick(eventName) {
    toastr.success(eventName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're updating the `angular.json` file, you need to be sure to *restart* the server and not just let it live update, if it's already running.